# Plotting axisymmetric solution to transient heat equation using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, heat-equation, axisymmetry

I'm having some trouble plotting my results from NDSolve in an appealing way. Below is how I tried to solve the heat equation for axisymmetric, transient diffusion in the radial direction only as a function of time. There is an internal heat generation term and constant temperature at the radial boundry (ro).

```
ro = .3;
l = 1;
s = 25;
\[Rho] = 1050; 
c = 4097;
k = .55;
q = 19305.6*Exp[.000139*t];
bc1 = T[ro, t] == s;
bc4 = (D[T[r, t], r] /. r -> 0.0001) == 0.0;
ic = T[r, 0] == s;

heat = D[T[r, t], r, r] + (1/r)*D[T[r, t], r] + q/k == (([Rho]*c)/k)*D[T[r, t], t];

sol = NDSolve[{heat, bc1, bc4, ic}, T[r, t], {r, .0001, ro}, {t, 0, 10000}]
```

When I plot my results, I get cartesian coordinates with radius on one axis, time on another axis, and temperature on the third axis.

```
Plot3D[T[r, t] /. sol, {r, .0001, .3}, {t, 0, 10000}]
```

[image]

This result is correct and interpretable; however, I'm looking to get a circular plot that shows me temperature at each radial position as time evolves. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sol = NDSolve[{heat, bc1, bc4, ic}, T, {r, .0001, ro}, {t, 0, 10000}]
f[a_, b_] := T[a, b] /. sol[[1]]
tab = Table[
   ParametricPlot3D[
    Evaluate[{u Cos[v], u Sin[v], f[u, j]}], {u, 0.0001, 0.3}, {v, 0, 
     2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 0.3}, {-0.3, 0.3}, {20, 150}}, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Mesh -> None], {j, 0, 10000, 100}];
```

`tab` exported as  animated gif:

[image]

or color-coding temperature (rescaling 20 to 120):

```
tab = Table[
   ParametricPlot3D[
    Evaluate[{u Cos[v], u Sin[v], f[u, j]}], {u, 0.0001, 0.3}, {v, 0, 
     2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 0.3}, {-0.3, 0.3}, {20, 150}}, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Mesh -> None, 
    ColorFunction -> 
     Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][(z - 20)/100]], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {j, 0, 10000, 500}];
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much! One final question: is it possible to place a bar legend that tells me the temperature represented by each color?

Comment: @ChaseKayrouz  you can add a legend using `Legended`. Wrap the plot in `Legended`, e.g. `Legended[plot,BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {20, 120}}]]`. See the documentation for legend titles etc. Good luck :)

Comment: You can also use 'RevolutionPlot3D[f[r, 10000], {r, 0, ro}]' instead of 'ParametricPlot3D', so you don't have to write out the parameterisation explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is sort of a quick and dirty way. We replace `r` with `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]` and define a piece-wise function as follows:

```
f[rr_, tt_] = If[rr >= 0.3 || rr <= 0.0001, 25, First@T[r, t] /. sol /. {r -> rr, t -> tt}]
```

Using `If` to give the values of the function on and outside the boundaries is necessary in order that we don't evaluate the `InterpolatingFunction` outside of its domain. Then, we `Plot3D` and `Manipulate` over time:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot3D[f[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], t],
    {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3},
    PlotRange -> {20, 140},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
  {t, 0, 10000}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is what I'm looking for! Unfortunately, when I try this I get "$Aborted" in the plot window.

Comment: @ChaseKayrouz. I see why. See the updated code.